# SyntaxHighlighter 3.0.83 on Blogger splits my source code

Tags: java, blogger, syntaxhighlighter

I'm trying to use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) 3.0.83 on Blogger in order to highlight some simple java code but my single java line is split in many chunks.
Here's what I did to set it up:

Blogger: Design | Template | Edit HTML

Added these lines right before </head>:

```
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeEmacs.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Then, added those lines right before the end of </body>:

```
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
SyntaxHighlighter.defaults.toolbar = false;
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

Then my post is:

```
<pre class="brush:java">MyJFrame.this.processWindowEvent(new WindowEvent(MyJFrame.this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSED));
</pre>
```

and what I get is:
[image]

How come my line is split using every word separator apparently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it:

I previously added CSS customisations to Blogger for the `<code>` HTML tag like this:

```
code {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    font: 0.8em 'Courier New', Courier, Fixed;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
    display: block;
}
```

and the culprit is `display : block;`, which perturbates SyntaxHighlighter.

Replacing `code {...}` with `pre code {...}` does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it on my blog and it works. You should just add all those tags, right before `</head>` tag. This is what I've for my blog:

```
<!--SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTER BEGINS-->
    <link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCSharp.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPhp.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPython.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushRuby.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushSql.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushVb.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPerl.js' type='text/javascript'/>
    <script language='javascript'>
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = &#39;http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/clipboard.swf&#39;;
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    </script>
    <!--SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTER ENDS-->
```

**`</head>`**

Comment: Gosh! No change with your solution on my blog. There must be something on the blog settings because on a simple HTML page, this setup works...

Comment: I tried your case and it works on my blog. So, it must be something else.